# How to change the data stored in LocalStorage when clicking on element in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, event-handling, local-storage

I am creating to-do app in react, and storing the data in localstorage,when user click on particular task it is mark completed, for that purpose i have "complete" boolean property for all task in localStorage.now i want to change that property onclick of that particular task,How to achieve this?.Here is the code link :
https://github.com/Khatri-Jinal/react-app/tree/practical4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you make a custom hook for local storage (ie. useLocalStorage). This ensures that when you update a value in the local storage, the components that are using the updated value are automatically re-rendered.

You may look it up online or use [this youtube viode](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6ThXsUwLWvc) for your reference. The first example there is useLocalStorage.

EDIT:
Your task variable should be an array of object. When rendering the task, pass an id or anything unique to the task on the onclick function (In this example, I'll just use task name but I advise to create your own).

```
// tasks hook
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([
  {desc: 'jog', isComplete: true},
  {desc: 'walk', isComplete: false},
  {desc: 'read', isComplete: true},
]);

// rendering tasks
tasks.map(task => {
  <div key={task.desc} onClick={() => onClickTask(task.desc)}
    task.desc
  </div>
});
```

And this is your onClickTask function

```
const onClickTask = (identifier) => {
  const index = tasks.findIndex(task => task.desc === identifier);
  const newTasks = [...tasks];
  newTasks[index].isComplete = true;

  setTasks(newTasks);
};
```

Comment: Great to hear, how about mark my answer as correct so other people can see that the answer worked for you?

Answer (score 1):

get the value from local storage and update it and then set it again
for ex:
`let data=localStorage.getItem('tasks')`
//make changes in data
`localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));`

Comment: but how to select particular task which is clicked, How can i get connection between clicked task and task for that data in local storage, how can i compare?

Comment: How, can i know, which task should i update?

Answer (score 0):

I made this solution, I hope it helps.

```
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState([]);

  // Get todo list from localStorage when the component is mounted
  useEffect(() => {
    setTodoList(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todoList')));
  }, [])

  function updateTodo(todoId, data) {
    const todoIndex = todoList.findIndex(todo => todo.id === todoId);
    // Get a copy of the todo
    let updatableTodo = { ...todoList[todoIndex] };

    // Update the todo here...
    updatableTodo.title = data.title;

    // Update the state and localStorage
    setTodoList(todoList => {
      const newTodoList = [...todoList];
      newTodoList[todoIndex] = updatableTodo;
      localStorage.setItem('todoList', JSON.stringify(newTodoList));
      return newTodoList;
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {todoList.map((todo) => 
        <button onClick={() => updateTodo(todo.id, data)} key={todo.id}>Update</button>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```